# SQL: Multiple columns in primary key - how to achieve correct order?

Tags: sql, performance, database-design, database-performance

In my solution I have multiple queries for my table. Let's assume that it's a table with multiple columns, but columns **a** and **b** form the **PrimaryKey**. Sometimes I query by **a** values, sometimes by **b** values. Currently I have `PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([a] ASC, [b] ASC)`. 
When I'm trying to query by column **b** it is very slow and I constantly get a timeout from the database.

Having two clustered primary keys would be great...
What shoud I do? Will creating a new index on column **b** make **b** queries more efficient?

Comment: Create a non-clustered index. If the non-clustered index covers your query then the query will typically run faster than it will using the clustered index. The choice of primary key is irrelevant as far as performance is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

Primary key is a *logical* concept. Performance, on the other hand, depends on the *physical* organization of data. The reason why `WHERE a = ?` is fast is not that PK exists, but that an index was automatically created together with the PK.

So, if you want to make another query fast, just add an appropriate index.

---

Assuming your table looks similar to this...

```
CREATE TABLE T (
    a int,
    b int,
    c int,
    PRIMARY KEY (a, b)
);
```

You have more-less the following options for creating an index to speed-up `WHERE b = ?`:

```
CREATE INDEX T_I1 ON T(b);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX T_I2 ON T(b, a);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX T_I3 ON T(b, a, c);
   -- or: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX T_I2 ON T(b, a) INCLUDE (c);
```

Which of these options you choose, depends largely on how much of your query you want to [cover](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-only-scan-covering-index).

---

Also, beware that...

```
CREATE INDEX T_I1 ON T(b);
```

...might actually be equivalent to...

```
CREATE INDEX T_I1 ON T(b) INCLUDE (a);
```

...if your table is [clustered](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index) (which it is in your case).